# Google Sheets MEDIAN Values from a single cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, median, gs-vlookup

With the formula below:

```
=IFNA(IF(AND(F5="",F5=0),0,MEDIAN((M4+((K5*(VLOOKUP(E5,TourData,4,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(AF$4,ClanData,2,FALSE))-((J5-K5)*VLOOKUP(E5,TourData,5,FALSE))))),C5:D5)),0)
```

Is it possible to take the second `MEDIAN` Value, C5:D5 and put that value in one cell? Currently C5=0 & D5=1000. Would it be possible to do something like 0/1000 in C5 and get the same results in the formula above? I’ve tried using `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, & `SPLIT()` with no success. The only caveat is that the number of characters before & after the delimiter '/' can be anywhere between 1 & 4 characters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the above formula works for you, you can do simple split like:

```
=IFNA(IF(AND(F5="", F5=0), 0, MEDIAN((M4+((K5*(
 VLOOKUP(E5,   TourData, 4, 0)+
 VLOOKUP(AF$4, ClanData, 2, 0))-((J5-K5)*
 VLOOKUP(E5,   TourData, 5, 0))))), SPLIT(C5, "/"))), 0)
```

[image]

Comment: So right now I have 0 in C5 for the MIN value, & 1000 in D5 for the MAX value. Instead of using two cells for the MIN/MAX values, I'd like to just use one cell, which would look like 0/1000 in C5. I'm not trying to combine text, I'm trying to extract text values from one cell.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y4PJ3Lc6t3fp5-WZ9lKcHmAEhB2z4nKSx9uRPx3akJ4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Row five has how I want it to be. M5 should show 4200 if the formula works correctly, otherwise, it'll show 4211. Row six is how it is now.